# How to iterate over each string in a list of strings and operate on its elements?

Tags: python, string, list

Given a list:

```py
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
```

I need to compare the first and the last element of each string in the list. If the first and the last element in the string is the same, then increment the count.

If I try it manually, I can iterate over each element of the strings in the list:

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
w1 = words[0]
print w1
aba

for i in w1:
   print i
 
a
b
a

if w1[0] == w1[len(w1) - 1]:
   c += 1
   print c
 
1
```

But, when I try to iterate over all the elements of all the strings in the list , using a `for` loop, I get an error.

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
c = 0
for i in words:
     w1 = words[i]
     if w1[0] == w1[len(w1) - 1]:
       c += 1
     print c
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How would I achieve comparing the first and the last element of a list of strings?

Comment: Iteration over a list returns its elements not indexes, hence the error.

Comment: Your Python one-liner to do what you want (but not solve or explain the bug) would look like: `c = sum([1 if w[0] == w[-1] else 0 for w in words])`. But that won't really help you until you start getting the hang of list-comprehensions (even shorter: `c = sum([int(w[0] == w[-1]) for w in words])`).

Comment: @Evert You can drop the `int` call and `[]` as well.. ;-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Hm, I don't like summing booleans like that, but I guess implicit conversion works here. I let it stand, otherwise your comment won't make sense ;-).

Comment: This question is awful; the title has nothing to do with the actual problem, and actively misleads people who arrive from a search engine. This is why it is important to attempt [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking. People who actually have the question in the title are also better served by other duplicates.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try:

```
for word in words:
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        c += 1
    print c
```

`for word in words` returns the items of `words`, not the index. If you need the index sometime, try using `enumerate`:

```
for idx, word in enumerate(words):
    print idx, word
```

would output

```
0, 'aba'
1, 'xyz'
etc.
```

The `-1` in `word[-1]` above is Python's way of saying "the last element". `word[-2]` would give you the second last element, and so on.

You can also use a generator to achieve this.

```
c = sum(1 for word in words if word[0] == word[-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion that using `range(len())` is the equivalent of using `enumerate()` is incorrect. They return the same results, but they are *not* the same.

Using `enumerate()` actually gives you key/value pairs. Using `range(len())` does not.

Let's check `range(len())` first (working from the example from the original poster):

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
    print range(len(words))
```

This gives us a simple list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

... and the elements in this list serve as the "indexes" in our results.

So let's do the same thing with our `enumerate()` version:

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']    
   print enumerate(words)
```

This certainly doesn't give us a list:

```
<enumerate object at 0x7f6be7f32c30>
```

...so let's turn it *into* a list, and see what happens:

```
print list(enumerate(words))
```

It gives us:

```
[(0, 'aba'), (1, 'xyz'), (2, 'xgx'), (3, 'dssd'), (4, 'sdjh')]
```

These are actual key/value pairs.

So this ...

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']

for i in range(len(words)):
    print "words[{}] = ".format(i), words[i]
```

... actually takes the first list (Words), and creates a *second*, simple list of the range indicated by the length of the first list.

So we have two simple lists, and we are merely printing one element from each list in order to get our so-called "key/value" pairs.

But they aren't really key/value pairs; they are merely two single elements printed at the same time, from different lists.

Whereas the `enumerate ()` code:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    print "words[{}] = {}".format(i, word)
```

... also creates a second list. But that list actually *is* a list of key/value pairs, and we are asking for each key and value from a single source -- rather than from two lists (like we did above).

So we print the same results, but the sources are completely different -- and handled completely differently.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that in your second example `i` is the word itself, not the index of the word. So

```
for w1 in words:
     if w1[0] == w1[len(w1) - 1]:
       c += 1
     print c
```

would the equivalent of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code outputs the number of words whose first and last letters are equal. Tested and verified using a [python online compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php):

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']  
count = 0  
for i in words:  
     if i[0]==i[-1]:
        count = count + 1  
print(count)
```

Output:

```
$python main.py
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use range() instead, like the following :

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c=0
words = ['challa','reddy','challa']

for idx, word in enumerate(words):
    if idx==0:
        firstword=word
        print(firstword)
    elif idx == len(words)-1:
        lastword=word
        print(lastword)
        if firstword==lastword:
            c=c+1
            print(c)
```

Comment: Could you please explain more details about your code?

Comment: Hi Serenity , Basically the code is getting increment number if first word and last words are same.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating trough items in words but you have to iterate through item's length:

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
c = 0
for i in range(len(words)):
    w1 = words[i]
    if w1[0] == w1[len(w1) - 1]:
      c += 1
    print (c)
```

In your case i[0] is 'aba' because i is calculated from items in words:

```
words = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']
c = 0
for i in words:
print(i)
```

the output is:

> aba

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using `sum()` and a generator expression. When intepreted as integers, booleans that are `True` have a value of `1`, and booleans that are `False` have a value of `0`. So, we can do the following:

```py
sum(word[0] == word[-1] for word in words)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for i,j in enumerate(words): # i---index of word----j
     #now you got index of your words (present in i)
     print(i)
```