# String being treated as group of characters when iterated

Tags: python, data-structures

First, I've sorted out my issue when I found this:
[in python: iterate over each string in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968823/in-python-iterate-over-each-string-in-a-list)

Originally I was getting what I thought was weird behavior when I would iterate over a "list" with a single string.  In those instances, the string was being treated as a group of characters, and the iteration was sequentially returning each character in the string.

Being new to Python, I did not realize there's a somewhat strict difference between using [] and () to define a list.  My list definitions were using ().  However, when the lists would contain more than one string, the iteration was return each complete string sequentially.  To illustrate:

```
list = ('string')
for i in list:
    print i
```

Output:

```
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

But if i do this, that is, add a second string to the () group:

```
list = ('string','another string')
for i in list:
    print i
```

It gets treated as if I used [] (as you're supposed to).  Output:

```
string
another string
```

Now, I get the expected behavior either way if I use [] to define my lists, so that's what I'm doing now.  I just thought this was interesting behavior.

Can someone point me towards some documentation that explains the way Python interprets parens, especially relative to strings?

I didn't see anything in the Python docs for data structures:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name. That trashes the reference to the `list` function

Comment: In Python strings are sequences of characters and characters are one character strings. `list`s are also sequences (of anything) and sometimes it can seem difficult to tell them apart.

Answer (score 3):

That's because parentheses don't define lists.  They sometimes define tuples `(a, b)`, which are similar to lists, but even in the code you provide, that is not a tuple.

```
('string')
```

Is a parenthesized expression.  It's value is `'string'`.

```
('string',)
```

Is a 1-tuple that contains a single element, the string `'string'`

Comment: Note that `tuples` are immutable. Elements cannot be added or removed. True `list` objects are denoted with brackets `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`, and unlike parenthesis, `[ 1 ]` is actually a 1-element list

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the parenthesis are ambiguous. Do you mean a single element tuple or do you mean a parenthesized expression? The Python parser assumes parenthesized expression. You then are iterating over the string:

```
>>> li = ('string')
>>> li
'string'
```

This is in contrast to creating a list literal or set literal with a single string literal since there is no ambiguity what you mean:

```
>>> ['string']
['string']
>>> {'string'}
set(['string'])
```

In the second case, you are creating a tuple with two elements and then iterating over that tuple:

```
>>> li = ('string','another string')
>>> li
('string', 'another string')
```

If you want the first case to act like the second case, add a comma to create a one element tuple:

```
>>> li = ('string',)
>>> li
('string',)
```

Or, you do not have to use parenthesis to define a tuple:

```
>>> 'string','another string'
('string', 'another string')
>>> 'string',
('string',)
```

The tuple constructor in this case is the comma which allows this idiom in Python for swapping values without a temporary variable:

```
>>> a='string'
>>> b='another string'
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> a
'another string'
>>> b
'string'
```

---

(And please do not use `list` as a variable name. That redefines the `list` function...)

Comment: thank you for that.  And yes, typically I would not do something like that with variable names, this was just quick and dirty pseudo-ish code.  :)