# How to parse words from strings in a list, when the list is in a tuple?

Tags: python

I am working backwards on my current task. I have data formatted as:

```
qn1 = (["123 + 12", "234 + 23"], True)
```

I need to read the strings of equations and parse the individual words. My problem is that I cannot split the strings in the list, because the list is in a tuple.

My desired output would be:

[image: Image is the output of >>> print(" 123 234\n""+ 12 + 23\n""==== ====").]

My search so far took me to;

[This other s/flow question; but that is not what am looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968823/how-to-iterate-over-each-string-in-a-list-of-strings-and-operate-on-its-element)

Please, do not solve the whole problem for me.
I like the challenge, (and it is part of my [freecodecamp](https://repl.it/repls/SoggyAttentiveDatum#README.md) exam)

I just need some pointers to get unstuck.

I have found that my question is different from the question [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python) in that I am not just splitting a tuple, I am splitting a list inside a tuple, (to further split the string inside at spaces so that i can select the numbers and "+" sign inside to arrange them.)

Comment: Look up how to unpack tuples and lists, then you can access the individual elements and split them.

Comment: ```qn1[0]``` gives you the first element of the tuple. ```qn1[0][0].split()``` give you ```['123', '+', '12']```, I hope that will help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split and parse a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: hey @Mark, i still have problems because `print(qn1[0][0][0])` gives me `1`. How can i make so that i get `123` which is what i want?

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert i have really tried but i cannot get the answer from that particular question.thank you

Comment: @Erick Kieti ```qn1[0][0].split()[0]``` gets you ```123``` and ```qn1[0][0].split()[1]``` gets you ```+```  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to split up the strings into lists so you can put them into print statements

hopefully, this should challenge you a bit :^)

```
qn1 = (["123 + 12", "234 + 23"], True)

eq1 = []
eq2 = []

#try to get a list of the parts of that equation. E.g ["567", "+", "56"]

print(f"{eq1[0]}     {eq2[0]}")
print(f"{eq1[1]} {eq1[2]}   {eq2[1]} {eq2[2]}")
print(f"====    ====")
```

Comment: yeah, it is a little challenging and awesome too.thank you i've been working on it and am not through yet but its no longer a brick wall.so thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the data from the tuple.

```
>>> qn1 = (["123 + 12", "234 + 23"], True)
>>> equations, flag = qn1
>>> equations
['123 + 12', '234 + 23']
```

Or you could use an index into the tuple:

```
>>> qn1 = (["123 + 12", "234 + 23"], True)
>>> equations = qn1[0]
>>> equations
['123 + 12', '234 + 23']
```

Next, split the equation into parts:

```
>>> for equation in equations:
...     tokens = equation.split()
...     print(tokens)
... 
['123', '+', '12']
['234', '+', '23']
```

To get started on parsing mathematical expressions see:
[**Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/1164465)

For ideas on formatting the output, see:
[**Create nice column output in python**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9989334/1164465)