# How to iterate over each words in a list

Tags: python

I am new to python. I need to iterate over words one by one from a list. But i can only iterate through each letters in each words vertically.

```py
l = ['abcd efgh ijkl']

for i in l:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

### Output:

```
a
b
c
d
 
e
f
g
h
 
i
j
k
l
```

### Expected output:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over each string in a list of strings and operate on its elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968823/how-to-iterate-over-each-string-in-a-list-of-strings-and-operate-on-its-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the string via spaces.

```
l = ["abcd efgh ijkl"]

for i in l:
    for j in i.split():
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a single element (the string `'abcd efgh ijkl'`) in the list, you need to split it:

```
l = ['abcd efgh ijkl']
for i in l:
    # this will split on whitespace,
    # you can split explicitly on space only split(' ')
    for j in i.split():                     
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['abcd efgh ijkl']
for word in l[0].split(" "):
    print(word)
```

Or for many strings with words:

```
l = ['abcd efgh ijkl', 'word1 word2', 'word3 word5']
for string in l:
    for word in string.split(" "):
        print(word)
```

Comment: `l` is a list, it doesn't have a `split()` method.

Comment: What if `l` has more than one element?

Comment: you're right, Edited answer

Answer (score -3):

You have an additional step in your code, try:

```
l = ['abcd efgh ijkl']
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This doesn't split the string into words. It will print all of `abcd efgh ijkl` on a single line.

Comment: Yeah totally missed that important detail

Answer (score -3):

Why are you using a second `for` loop?
The words must be within quotes.

```py
l = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

In `ipython`

```py
In [110]: l = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
     ...:
     ...: for i in l:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the input.